# Give extra parameter to custom validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am experimenting with the Angular2 Form Validation and wand to check if the value is already taken:

```
namesArray = Users[];
ngOnInit() {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        this.nameValidator
      ])
      ],
 })
}

nameValidator(control:FormControl):{[key:string]:boolean} {
    console.log(this.namesArray);
    return null;
}
```

this returns me an error:

**Cannot read property 'namesArray' of undefined**

When I print `this` is returns undefined. So how can I access an array that is outside of the function?

Comment: Have you tried to retain context like `this.nameValidator.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in fat arrow function to retain `this`

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        (control) => this.nameValidator(control as FormControl)
      ])
      ],
 })
}
```

More about fat arrow here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Returns `Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'`

Comment: Hey I edited it. You can either cast it to `FormControl` when using fat arrow or change the signature of the validation function to allow `AbstractControl` parameter.